# Shapefile size limits in Mapbox

Tags: shapefile, mapbox

I'm creating a style in Mapbox which is supposed to contain hundreds of shapefiles for a total size (shp + dbf) of several GBs. Due to the limit of 15 sources per style, I've combined the smaller shapefiles into shapefiles of about 250 MB, and styled the data from the different shapefiles accordingly to the name of their original shapefiles.
Unfortunately, this is not enough for representing all my data within the style because I exceed the limit of 15 sources x 260 MB each.

Am I doing the above correctly or am I missing something that would allow myself to use more sources?

EDIT: I'm experimenting with Tippecanoe and MBtiles. Hopefully it will not oversimplify my shapes.